# Is a Windows AD credential combined with AD group membership 2 factor authentication?

Tags: authentication

We have a requirement for 2-factor authentication for our internal WiFi SSID's.
Currently we use PEAP w/ MS-CHAPv2 to pass windows creds through the AP to a RADIUS server (A Domain Controller running NPS).  This has been recently been accused of not being 2-Factor authentication because it's only supplying 'something you know' in the form of your windows credentials..

However, on the NPS server they have to be a member of one of two groups in AD as well to be allowed on, so in my book that would be 'something you are'. Making it two-factor..  So is our current setup really two-factor or not.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion of "two factor authentication" is not a strictly defined mathematical notion. However, *usually*, it relates to having two *factors* for *authentication*.

The second term is important: you are trying to authenticate a user, i.e. to make sure that the user is indeed at the other end of the line. Right now. When looking up the account membership in the AD server, you are not verifying whether the human user is there or not. Indeed, the user account is *still* a member of the groups even when the user is not there at all. Thus, verifying group membership is not authentication at all. Nothing in the AD will tell you: "yeah, you are talking to Bob right now". At best, the AD will tell you: "there exists a user known as Bob".

AD group memberships are not authentication. As such, they cannot be an authentication factor. What AD group memberships relate is **authorization**, a completely distinct concept.

Comment: A follow up then.. If we added a pre-shared-key to that same SSID, and changed to certificate based auth would it be two factor?  Something you know, the SSIDs PSK, something you have, the cert??

Comment: Well, Yes, a certificate can be considered a second authentication factor. However, it is not flexible I mean, let us assume I am using my note book, tablet and mobile device inn your network do I get one certificate for each device.

Comment: The idea atm is that you'd have to import your cert to each of your devices to allow it on.  I mean if there was a way to layer the PEAP/MSCHAPv2 and EAP-TLS to do win and cert auth that would be ideal, but I haven't seen that it is.. and we HAVE to have 2-factor auth, one way or another and PSK + cert is all I can think of that doesn't require us to spend money.  I'm open to ideas though..

Comment: No. The PSK is something someone knew once upon a time, but it is not evidence that the user-right-this-second knows the secret. 2FA does not say "something you *knew*", it's "something you *know*". Present tense.

Comment: I believe that BASEL II considers 2 passwords to be 2-factor authentication (password and "secret answer"). A key question is then whether you need two-factor authentication for the network or for the services running on the network - in the later case, access to the WIFI might be considered as a seperate authentication factor while a username and password for an application would be the second factor.

Answer (score 1):

Factors are:

1. Something you know - e.g. a password
2. Something you have - e.g. a smart card or token
3. Something you are - a biometric

Two factor authentication requires two of the above from different sets. For example a pin and a password is still single factor as it's two "something you know" items.

A certificate, although it is technically classified as something you have, can often be digitally stolen. This means that if an end user is infected my malware such as Zeus both their credentials and their certificates can often be extracted allowing account compromise. If the certificate is stored in a hardware security module or TPM it can be very secure.

Likewise some phone based schemes can be thought of as a true "something you have factor" though again care should be taken.

Your AD group membership is authorisation not authentication.

Comment: Your classification of a certificate (in reality the private key) as a very long password and not a "true" second factor disagrees with accepted industry definitions.  Yes, it can be stolen but that has no bearing on the fact that it is a valid 'something you have' authentication factor.

Comment: Perhaps but given the prevalence of certificate stealing malware I think personally it shouldn't be considered a full 2nd factor - though I accept this may differ from other viewpoints. And it's true it's better than nothing - I just don't believe it's as effective a something that can't be digitally stolen. I'll update my answer.